# Trying to Deploy a Vite app installed with pnpm to github actions

Tags: github-actions, vite, pnpm

The script keeping hitting a wall telling me :

```
Error: Unable to resolve action actions/actions-gh-pages, repository not found
```

the build section works fine every installs correctly but when the install reach the deploy section it stops and gives the above error
this is the script i used :

```
name: pnpm Example Workflow
on:
 push:
jobs:
 build:
runs-on: ubuntu-latest
strategy:
  matrix:
    node-version: [18]
steps:
- uses: actions/checkout@v3
- uses: pnpm/action-setup@v2
  with:
    version: 7
- name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
  uses: actions/setup-node@v3
  with:
    node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
    cache: 'pnpm'
- name: Install dependencies
  run: pnpm install
- name: Build
  run: pnpm run build
deploy:
  environment:
  name: github-pages
  #  url: ${{steps.deployment.outputs.page_url}}
runs-on: ubuntu-latest
steps:
 
  - name: Setup Pages
    uses: actions/configure-pages@v3
  - name: Upload artifact
    uses: actions/upload-pages-artifact@v1
    with:
      # Upload dist repository
      path: .
  - name: Deploy
    uses: actions/actions-gh-pages@v3
    with:
      # Upload dist repository
      path: .
```

what ever solution i try to make it work it does not, can you help where is my mistake ?

**EDIT: The solution  from the answer made it work. but now i won't give me the link to deployment**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you want the following action [peaceiris/actions-gh-pages](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/github-pages-action). If this is the case you need to change your "Deploy" step to something like:

```yaml
- name: Deploy
  uses: peaceiris/actions-gh-pages@v3
  with:
    github_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
    publish_dir: ./public
```

You can check out the link above for more information about how to configure the aforementioned action.

Comment: i have another issue this solution didn't give me the url to page

Comment: From the [GitHub Pages docs](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/about-github-pages#types-of-github-pages-sites):

Unless you're using a custom domain, project sites are available at `http(s)://<username>.github.io/<repository>` or `http(s)://<organization>.github.io/<repository>`.

Comment: link not working. 
after removing the comment from this line  #  url: ${{steps.deployment.outputs.page_url}}

i get this error: 

deploy
Environment URL '' is not a valid http(s) URL, so it will not be shown as a link in the workflow graph.